# Drawing a tooltip with a border

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable

I am trying to achieve an a bordered tooltip like this (well not exactly, just the part where I want to have a smooth border):

[image]

So far, this is what I have tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:gravity="top|right">

        <rotate android:fromDegrees="45" android:toDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="0%" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <size android:width="24dp" android:height="24dp" />
                <stroke android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" android:width="1dp"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="206dp" android:height="76dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <stroke android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"  android:width="1dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:gravity="top|right">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="45" android:toDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="0%" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <size android:width="24dp" android:height="24dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            </shape>

        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Here's my output:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get a 9 patch drawable for this somewhere?

Comment: In the SDK resources on your hard drive there are actually some speech balloons in the form of 9 patches. Search for `popup_inline_error*.9.png`. The ones I found are pinkish. But can easily edited in Gimp. Or find new ones by googling (maybe not already available as 9 patches - a little effort may be required).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got something working, though it's not perfect. Here's the output:

[image]
Notice the edges are not very smooth. Here's the modified code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:gravity="top|right" android:right="10dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="45" android:toDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="0%" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <size android:width="24dp" android:height="24dp" />
                <stroke android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" android:width="1dp"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="206dp" android:height="76dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <stroke android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"  android:width="1dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:gravity="top|right" android:right="10dp" android:top="1dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="45" android:toDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="0%" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <size android:width="24dp" android:height="24dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            </shape>

        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: I will go with 9 patch, I thought of sharing this solution if someone needs in future.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use 9-patch. On Android Studio, choose "create 9-patch file" :

[image]

Then, have the left and top marking for the parts you wish to duplicate the larger/smaller you have the image.

And have the right and bottom markings for the parts you wish to have the content.

On many cases, those are the same areas. but on your case, I think it won't be as such.

I also suggest to make the image as small as possible, so that it will take minimal size that you allow it to be. This would save a bit of space.

You can read more about those on the docs:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawables#nine-patch
- https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch